# Prove that if $\dim X < \dim Y$ then $\dim(Y \setminus X) = \dim Y$.

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

Let $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and prove that if $\dim X < \dim Y$ then;
\begin{equation}
\dim(Y \setminus X) = \dim Y
\end{equation}
The trivial case is easy (where $Y \cap X = \emptyset)$, since then we would simply have $Y \setminus X = Y$.

When $Y \cap X \neq \emptyset$, I thought the best way to show this case would be by proving the two inequalities separately. For the inequality $\dim(Y\setminus X) \leq \dim Y$:

We know that $\dim(Y\setminus X) = \dim(Y \cap X^c)$, so intuitively, I would like to be able to show that:
\begin{equation}
\dim(Y \cap X^c) = \inf\{\dim Y, \dim X^c\}
\end{equation}

Since then this inequality would follow immediately. Not too sure how to go about this though, or how to begin with the other inequality. Any help and thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: What is $\dim(X)$ for an arbitrary subset $X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I'm using the definition of dimension here as Hausdorff dimension (sorry I should have mentioned). I.e. $\dim X=  \inf \{ s >0 : \mathcal{H}^s(X) = 0\}$.

Comment: you should probably include that in your question.

Comment: I suppose we want $X$ and $Y$ to be measurable. If $\dim X < \dim Y$ then, for $\alpha$ such that $\dim X < \alpha < \dim Y$, $\mathcal{H}^s(X)=0$ and $\mathcal{H}^s(Y)=\infty$. Thus, $\mathcal{H}^s(Y\setminus X) = \infty$. Your result follows.